# Adding a property to an input element with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion

I created an input element with emotion react, and that input element has a custom property named pointer:

```
  <InputField
    placeholder={placeholder}
    pointer={insidePool}
    readOnly={insidePool}
    type={type}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
```

The InputField object:

```
    const InputField = styled('input')(({ pointer }) => ({
      all: 'unset',
      width: 200,
      display: 'inline-flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
     .....
    }));
```

TS is complaining that `pointer` doesn't exist on the input element. I'm trying to add an interface for it like so:

```
export interface ExtendedInput
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
    HTMLInputElement
  > {
  pointer: boolean;
}
```

And then assigning it to the InputField creation object:

```
const InputField: ExtendedInput = styled('input')(({ pointer }) => ({
```

Then TS complains that property pointer is missing in that styled object, and also complaining that the InputField in JSX:
JSX element type 'InputFIeld' does not have any construct or call signatures.

I know it's possible to solve this with ts-ignore, and such, but would really like to solve it with an interface is possible.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it’s styled.input not styled(input)… have you tried that?

Comment: No that bit is ok for sure

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitely pass a type to the `styled` generic like this `styled<{ pointer: boolean }>('input')`

Comment: I've tried, and gettign the error Type {pointer: boolean} does not satisfy the constraint keyOf InstrinsicElements

Comment: @sir-haver try changing the order to ```styled('input')<{ pointer: boolean }>(({ pointer } => ...))```